# Questions about documenting nested array and object data with jsDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How do I format nested arrays and objects using jsdoc?

This is my best guess:

```
an_obj = { 
        username1 : [
            {
                param1 : "value 1-1-1",
                param2 : "value 1-1-2",
                optional_nested : "1-1--2"
            },
            {
                param1 : "value 1-2-1",
                param2 : "value 1-2-2"
            },
        ],
        username2 : [
            {
                param1 : "value 2-1-1",
                param2 : "value 2-1-2"
            },
            {
                param1 : "value 2-2-1",
                param2 : "value 2-2-2",
                optional_nested : "2-2--2"              

            }
        ]
    }
}


/**
 * A function description.
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @param {Object} obj.username  This is not the object name, but a name type. 
 * @param {Array}  obj.username.array Desc...  using [] would conflict with optional params.
 *                                    However this could be confused with an object called array.
 * @param {String} obj.username.array.param1 Desc... This is the object name rather than a type.
 * @param {String} obj.username.array.param2 Desc... 
 * @param {String} obj.username.array.[optional_param] Desc... 
 */
var myFunc = function(obj){
    //...
};
myFunc(an_obj);
```

How do I indicate that an object is indexed by a kind of string?

How do I define a nested array?

Also not sure where to put the square brackets in the optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking [this](http://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Annotating+JavaScript+using+JSDoc;jsessionid=0F98A99DCDD90096053D08B4D1CAFDCB) out.  I'd probably write it something like this:

```
//{Object{username:<Array<Object{param1:String, param2:String,[optional_nest]:string}>>}}
```

Comment: Link is dead and the above example throws "Invalid type expression" with jsdoc 3.3

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it like this : (as specified here http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam)

```
/**
* @param {String[]} obj.username.array
*/
```

This is supposed to declare `obj.username.array` as an array of strings.
Are you using jsdoc or jsdoc3?

Comment: I'm currently using jsdoc-toolkit v3. I can't figure out how to deal with something like this {id: 'moo', items: [{url: '...',description: 'moo2'},...]}

Comment: This doesn't help, the case is documenting arrays of anonymous objects, not arrays of real objects